# how can I perform wudu & salat easily?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, wudu, muslim-practices

Assalamualaikum.
I am a young muslim. I have trouble with salat and wudu.
It has been better than before, but I still take long, and taking long is my main problem.
I take long in wudu because of how i do it. Salah is okay, i just have to fix my pronounciation.
How can I perform wudu and salah like everyone else; simple, in a short time and properly? especially with wudu.
Do you have any tips?
May Allah (praise be to Him) reward you all.

Comment: Your question is a bit imprecise. I would suggest that you try to formulate a question on wudu alone and describe what it is that you feel it is complicated. If you search for techniques to memorize and learn salat, better put it in a separate question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.